# Execute a command at the beginning and at the end of each method (Java and/or C++)

Tags: java, c++

I am working with Java and C++, my question is related to both languages.

I would like to write a command, which is executed at the beginning and at the end of each method, something like:

```
public class myClass: // does it need to be derived from some base class?
  private int information;
  public get_information();
  void write_message(String str_Msg)
    {
       System.out.println(get_information());
    }
  ...
```

The idea is to see something like this (when launching the `write_message()` method):

```
myClass():write_message().start
  myClass():get_information().start
    <the mentioned information>
  myClass():get_information().stop
myClass():write_message().stop
```

So, as you can imagine, the command should be something like:

```
System.out.println(StackDepth(" ") + "__CLASS__:__FUNCTION__().start"); // at the beginning
System.out.println(StackDepth(" ") + "__CLASS__:__FUNCTION__().stop");  // at the end
```

Anybody have an idea on how to do this? (I know, the pseudo-code is an awful mixture or Java and C :-) )

Comment: Modifying compiler to do code injection?

Comment: Looks like you want to *log* data.  I recommend searching the internet for "c++ logging".

Comment: No answer can be for both C++ and Java, so you have two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this in Java is to wrap your class in another class. The wrapper class must contain the same methods as the wrapped class and will delegate calls that are made to it:

```
class Test {
    public interface MessageWriter {
        void writeMessage(String str);
    }

    public static class MyClass implements MessageWriter {
        public void writeMessage(String str) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    public static class Wrapper implements MessageWriter {
        private MessageWriter writer;

        public Wrapper(MessageWriter writer) {
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        public void writeMessage(String str) {
            System.out.println("Method start");
            writer.writeMessage(str);
            System.out.println("Method stop");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(new MyClass());
        wrapper.writeMessage("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Method start
Hello world
Method stop
```

Basically you will implement the functionality that you want before and after each method call in the wrapper. The class wrapped by the wrapper will then do the actual work.

Note that the wrapper will only work for any class that implements the MessageWriter interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for something like [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) with which you can specify code to run around your method invocations...

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in C++ is to use a simple structure which is destroyed on scope exit, e.g.

```
struct FuncOp {
  FuncOp(const char* name) : name_(name) { cout << "entry: " << name_ << endl; }
~FuncOp() { cout << "exit: " << name_ << endl; }
  const char* name_;
};

void foo() {
  FuncOp op{ __PRETTY_FUNCTION_ };
}
```